# Where are these requests come from?

Tags: http

I'm using fiddler to analysis the requests of a site. The following `GET`

```
GET https://tss.sfs.db.com/websso/sso_FallThrough.sso?Xe47eKuUc4rm2LW9V1BHSzU1....
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2016 16:13:19 GMT
Server: dweb
Set-Cookie: CTSESSION=AAAAAQABAHid6vs1jduDPC1Q9ItYbjKC6Ih4bImKPTYYA6fOLowLvtT%2FsUj%2F2o7kl4ovRmo8qfOQjQgx%2B%2BQL6%2F6sspncrVYJOc62ijGMQ67Z9L%2FaklW42jLwx6BzfN2BUAiw5fU4lemLzDDlX0pGSNY1kXVCaqOS5UlOX8z62hA%3D; domain=tss.sfs.db.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: /investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index
Content-Length: 235
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

The `Location` header redirects it to

```
GET https://tss.sfs.db.com/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index
```

And the response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2016 16:13:19 GMT
Server: dweb
Content-Length: 1500
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=r73A_C0735ZlDXOeMyM7w9hSgnkMUHloIm3qIdgMKkHZ3KSPi30f!-828505221; path=/; HttpOnly
DB-Nickname: VTJGc2RHVmtYMStCbW4yYnlaQ2Ywei9pRHlENzd3aHFQYlhVNWZSbXFJUT0=
X-DB-NAR: 26564-1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/stylesheets/application_internet.xsl'?><application servleturi="/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web">
<menu href="Web?document=menu"/>
<clock href="/html/invest/clock.html"/>
<main href="Web?document=viewPortfolio&amp;portfolio=my">View All</main>
<headerlink class="blue_11" href="https://www.tss.db.com" style="margin-left:196px" target="root">TSS Home</headerlink>
<headerlink class="blue_11" href="http://www.db.com/index_e.htm" target="root">DB Home</headerlink>
<headerlink class="blue_11" href="Web?document=home" target="main">Home</headerlink>
<headerlink class="blue_11" href="Web?document=Contact" target="main">Contacts</headerlink>
<headerlink class="blue_11" href="/html/invest/FAQS.html" target="main">FAQs</headerlink>
<headerlink class="blue_11" href="logout" target="">Logout</headerlink>
<subheaderlink class="horizontal_navi first" href="https://www.tss.db.com" target="root">Trust &amp; Securities Services</subheaderlink>
<subheaderlink class="horizontal_navi" href="Web?document=home" target="main">Home</subheaderlink>
<search class="white_11">Search by:</search>
<search checked="true" class="blue_11_bold" id="r1">CUSIP</search>
<search class="blue_11_bold" id="r2">ISIN</search>
<search class="blue_11_bold" id="r3">Issuer</search>
<parameters>
<parameter name="document">index</parameter>
<parameter name="release.build.name">4.3.15 2016-05-26   </parameter>
</parameters>
</application>
```

However, there are the following requests after it. Where are they come from? There is no `Location`, meta or client side Javascript to redirect?

```
GET https://tss.sfs.db.com/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index&frame=topbar&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN= HTTP/1.1
GET https://tss.sfs.db.com/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index&frame=content&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN= HTTP/1.1
GET https://tss.sfs.db.com/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index&frame=bottombar&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN= HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML document has a [stylesheet](https://tss.sfs.db.com/stylesheets/application_internet.xsl) assigned to it:

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/stylesheets/application_internet.xsl'?>
```

That stylesheet makes a web browser convert the XML to HTML, and that HTML contains three `<frame>` tags:

```html
<frameset frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
    <xsl:attribute name="rows">134,*,35</xsl:attribute>
    <!-- always have a topbar -->
    <frame noresize="noresize" name="topbar" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no">
        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$uri"/>?document=<xsl:value-of select="$document"/>&amp;frame=topbar&amp;OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=<xsl:value-of select="$owasp_csrftoken"/></xsl:attribute>
    </frame>                
    <!-- always have a content row -->
    <frame noresize="noresize" name="content" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no">
        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$uri"/>?document=<xsl:value-of select="$document"/>&amp;frame=content&amp;OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=<xsl:value-of select="$owasp_csrftoken"/></xsl:attribute>
    </frame>
    <!-- always have a bottombar -->
    <frame noresize="noresize" name="bottombar" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no">
        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$uri"/>?document=<xsl:value-of select="$document"/>&amp;frame=bottombar&amp;OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=<xsl:value-of select="$owasp_csrftoken"/></xsl:attribute>
    </frame>                
</frameset>
```

Where:

- `$uri` is `https://tss.sfs.db.com/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web`.
- `$document` is `index`.
- `$owasp_csrftoken` is blank.

Thus producing this HTML:

```html
<frameset frameborder="no" framespacing="0" rows="134,*,35">
    <!-- always have a topbar -->
    <frame noresize="noresize" name="topbar" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="https://tss.sfs.db.com/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index&frame=topbar&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN="/>
    <!-- always have a content row -->
    <frame noresize="noresize" name="content" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="https://tss.sfs.db.com/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index&frame=content&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN="/>
    <!-- always have a bottombar -->
    <frame noresize="noresize" name="bottombar" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="https://tss.sfs.db.com/investauthenticated/servlet/web/Web?document=index&frame=bottombar&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN="/>
</frameset>
```

Which are the three URLs you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks. Is the xslt transformation occurred at browser/client side? I didn't see the xsl file downloaded in my logged sessions. Maybe it was downloaded before I logged if it's true?

Comment: The transformation is client-side.  The server only sends the XML and stylesheet, and then the browser interprets them and translates for display.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Got it. The xsl file should be downloaded before I started to record the session then.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: it would be downloaded when the XML provided by the redirected response gets parsed.  Since you recorded that response, and the subsequent HTML requests, you should have recorded the stylesheet download as well: `GET https://tss.sfs.db.com/stylesheets/application_internet.xsl`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Strangely I don't see it between the xml file request and the three iframe requests. There are only a css file `GET https://tss.sfs.db.com/css/invest/standard_internet.css HTTP/1.1` and some "Tunnel to" (`CONNECT tss.sfs.db.com:443 HTTP/1.1`).

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: It is likely being requested through the `CONNECT` tunnel since it is using HTTPS. Fiddler can [decrypt HTTPS-protected traffic](http://www.enhanceie.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Both the "Capture HTTPS CONNECTs" and "Decrypt HTTPS traffice" have been checked. Are these "Tunnel to" have data transferred too?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: Yes, the tunnels have data in them. `CONNECT` allows a client to ask an HTTP proxy server to connect to a target server, and then the client and target server can communicate with each other.  This is commonly used for (but is not limited to) proxying HTTPS.  See [Tunneling TCP based protocols through Web proxy servers](https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt), which is also covered by [RFC 2817](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2817) sections [5.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2817#section-5.2) and [5.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2817#section-5.3).

Comment: The check boxes are already checked. Is there any other options in fiddler? And why the content of other HTTPS requests are displayed in fiddler? Very strange.